# ERROR in Path must be string. Received undefined webpack: failed to compile

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

I wanted to start my angular2 app on webpack first time, and I get : ERROR in Path must be string. Received undefined webpack: failed to compile, that's the package.json`

```
{
  "name": "angular2-webpack-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An Angular 2 Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular 2 (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",
  "author": "Patrick Stapleton <patrick@angularclass.com>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "npm cache clean && rimraf node_modules doc typings coverage dist",
    "clean:dist": "rimraf dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "watch:dev": "webpack --watch --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch:prod": "webpack --watch --config webpack.prod.config.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:dev": "webpack --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached  --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver:start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "lint": "tsconfig-lint",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "e2e": "ts-node node_modules/.bin/protractor",
    "e2e:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "test": "karma start",
    "ci": "npm run e2e && npm run test",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json --exclude **/*.spec.ts ./src/",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "fix:ng2-clean": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf node_modules/angular2/manual_typings node_modules/angular2/typings node_modules/angular2/bundles/typings",
    "fix:ng2": "npm run fix:ng2-clean",
    "pretypings-install": "npm run fix:ng2",
    "typings-install": "typings install",
    "postinstall": "npm run typings-install",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "^1.5.5",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es6-promise-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "http-server": "^0.8.5",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.1.3",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^1.1.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.3",
    "protractor": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "ts-helper": "0.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "ts-node": "^0.5.5",
    "tsconfig-lint": "^0.5.0",
    "tslint": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "^1.7.5",
    "typings": "^0.6.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.4"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1 <= 5",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

Idk what to do, can you guys help me? Everything seems to be ok.`

Comment: Have you considered using the Angular CLI? It sets up an Angular project with Webpack and takes care of all of the configuration for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related with Node 6 and above. Changing it for Node 5.x instead will probably fix the issue.